# Vuejs Component Communication

Tags: highcharts, vuejs2

I am trying to do communication between two components using **$emit** and **$on**:

I am unable to communicated between the two components and unable to update **highcharts-chart** in component-B from click event in component-A.

**JavaScript Code for Component-A:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

const bus = new Vue();

const pause = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));


export default {

  data: () => ({
    active: [],
    avatar: null,
    open: [],
    users: [],
  }),

  computed: {
    items() {
      return [
        {
          name: 'Users',
          children: this.users,
        },
      ];
    },
    selected() {
      if (!this.active.length) return undefined;

      const id = this.active[0];

      return this.users.find(user => user.id === id);
    },
  },

  methods: {

    fetchData() {
      const id = this.active[0];
      this.parts = this.users.find(user => user.id === id);
      bus.$emit('new_parts', this.parts.data);
      console.log(this.parts.data);
    },


    async fetchUsers(item) {
      // Remove in 6 months and say
      // you've made optimizations! :)
      await pause(1500);

      return fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/toppartsdata')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => (item.children.push(...json)))
        .catch(err => console.warn(err));
    },

  },
};
```

**JavaScript Code for Component-B:**

```
    import VueHighcharts from 'vue2-highcharts';
import Vue from 'vue';

const bus = new Vue();

const asyncData = {
  name: 'Prediction Chart',
  marker: {
    symbol: 'circle',
  },
  data: [],
};
export default {
  components: {
    VueHighcharts,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          title: '',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'LINECOST',
          },
          labels: {
            formatter() {
              return `${this.value}°`;
            },
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          crosshairs: true,
          shared: true,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          spline: {
            marker: {
              radius: 4,
              lineColor: '#666666',
              lineWidth: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [],
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names

      bus.$on('new_parts', (data) => {
        alert(value);
      });
    },
    load() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      bus.$on('new_parts', function (data) {
        this.asyncData.data = data;
      });
      const { lineCharts } = this.$refs;
      lineCharts.delegateMethod('showLoading', 'Loading...');
      setTimeout(() => {
        lineCharts.addSeries(asyncData.data);
        lineCharts.hideLoading();
      }, 2000);
    },
  },
};
```

I want to be able to update my highcharts timeline graph using click events from component-A and update the data coming from the event to component-B everytime click the new button.

Comment: I dont think this code will work since `bus` at component A and `bus` at component B is different. You should catch event from parent component and execute the logic.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the real code you're using in both components, then it doesn't work because you're creating 2 different buses instead of reusing the same bus for events.

Try pulling it out in a separate file, such as `bus.js`, then export it and import it in the components where you need to interact with it:

```
// bus.js
export default new Vue()

// Component A
import bus from './bus'

bus.$emit('new_parts', this.parts.data)

// Component B
import bus from './bus'

bus.$on('new_parts', (data) => {
  alert(value);
})
```

Let me know if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: I followed your example but now highcharts is not updating when i click and emit the event.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle is to use the this.$root to emit and listen to the event:

To emit the event from component-a:

```
this.$root.$emit('new_parts', this.parts.data)
```

To listen to the event on component b:

```
 mounted() {
            this.$root.$on('new_parts', (data) => {
                //Your code here

            });
        },
```

Please add the onclick in the mounted method.

Here is a good article on events on Vue: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-components-communication/

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the updated code for my highcharts component:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vue-highcharts :options="options" ref="lineCharts"></vue-highcharts>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHighcharts from 'vue2-highcharts';
import { bus } from '../../../main';


export default {

  props: {
    partsdata: {
      type: Array,
    },
  },


  components: {
    VueHighcharts,

  },
  data() {
    return {

      options: {
        chart: {
          type: 'spline',
          title: 'Hassaan',
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: '',
          },
          labels: {
            formatter() {
              return `${this.value}°`;
            },
          },
        },
        tooltip: {
          crosshairs: true,
          shared: true,
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        plotOptions: {
          spline: {
            marker: {
              radius: 4,
              lineColor: '#666666',
              lineWidth: 1,
            },
          },
        },
        series: [],
      },
    };
  },


  created() {
    bus.$on('new_user', (data) => { this.series = data; });
  },

};
</script>
```

Comment: I am unable to update the highcharts from bus.$emit from the other component.

Answer (score 0):

Your last code is almost correct, however here is the wrong part:

**Wrong code:**

```
created() {
   bus.$on('new_user', (data) => { this.series = data; });
}
```

`this.series` is not referring to series data, instead, you're adding a new property to the whole component object. In your case it should look like that:

**Correct code:**

```
created() {
   bus.$on('new_user', (data) => { this.options.series[0].data = data; });
}
```

I prepared you an online example using **highcharts-vue** official Highcharts wrapper for VUE which I recommend you. There you will find working code with communication between components.

**Demo:** 
https://codesandbox.io/s/r0qmqjljwq